# BPMN: multiple roles in a row

Tags: bpmn

How do I model a process which can start by either Role1 OR Role2 performing the first task? I would not like to use "Role1 or Role2" in the lane description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [BPMN specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0.2/PDF) does explicitly not specify the exact purpose of lanes (p. 304/335 in PDF).

Consequently, the approach *Role1 or Role2* is actually compliant with the specification. The approach is also not far away from good practice. Adding multiple roles and even individual users as *candidates* to a task is often possible when configuring processes in BPX (Business Process eXecution) systems.

Typically, you would create a new role that encapsulates both *Role1* and *Role2* - let's call it *Role1;2*. This makes sense from an information systems perspective. For example, if you execute the process with IT support, you need to grant *Role1* and *Role2* access to the system/component that allows executing your *first task*. When configuring the access rights, the administrator will create a new user group - *Role1;2* that contains the the user groups *Role1* and *Role2*.

Note that a *process role* doesn't necessarily map to a *job title*. For example, a person who is employed as a *Software engineer* might share the process role *Specification writer* with a *System analyst*.

Comment: Thanks Timotheus. What if not all tasks in a lane are performed by these two roles? Example: 2 roles in the process, both of them can complete the first task but as soon as the first task is completed, the roles for the following tasks are clearly defined

Comment: Then, the same concept applies, which means you have to create separate lanes. In the example I mentioned: The role _specification writer_ is an own lane, containing the task _write user story_. Because the role _specification writer_ is applicable to both _software engineers_ and _system analysts_, either of them can take the task. The following task - _implement feature_, for example - is then in the _software engineer_ lane, because it can be handled by this role only.

Comment: Thank you. So there is no way to handle this in the two existing lanes of software engineer and system analyst at all? The model is complicated already and I would prefer not to create a separate lane for just one tasks that is performed by the roles which already exist in the model.